# Continuous Mapping Theorem: Why is this set measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability) of the Continuous Mapping Theorem on Wikipedia, how does one show that the set
$$B_{\delta} = \{x \notin D_{g} \: : \: \exists y \in S \text{ such that } d_{S}(x, y) < \delta \text{ but } d_{S^{\prime}}(g(x), g(y)) > \epsilon\} $$
is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $S$?

I changed the notation a bit since the result is stated generally for an a.e. continuous mapping $g: S \to S^{\prime}$ between two (separable, I presume) metric spaces, $S$ and $S^{\prime}$.

Comment: A book by Billingsley may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your space is separable then the distance function on it is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the product space.  For a proof see Parthasarathy's measure and probability book.  If we set $G(x,y)=d_{S'}(g(x),g(y))$ and $H(x,y)=d_{S}(x,y)$ then both $G$ and $H$ are measurable functions from $S \times S$ to $R$.  Notice that $W=G^{-1}(0,\delta) \cap H^{-1}(\epsilon,\infty) \cap D_g^c \times S$ is measurable in $S \times S$.  Since $S$ is separable, $W=A \times B$ for measurable $A$ and $B$ in the borel algebra.  Notice that the set $A$ is exactly $B_{\delta}$.

Comment: Thanks. One question: Is every Borel measurable set $W$ of $S \times S$ of the form $A \times B$? I thought the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $S \times S$ was simply generated by those rectangles.

Comment: yes, see page 56, proposition 13.11 of Parthasarathy's probability and measure book